# How to compile android goldfish 3.4 kernel and run on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source

First let me tell you that I am working on MAC with OS X 10.7.5. I am trying to compile Goldfish 3.4 kernel and run it on emulator. It compiles alright but when I run it the emulator opens and freezes. When I do a "top", I can see the emulator running like crazy but nothing turns up on the screen. Here is how I compiled the kernel

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish.git
git checkout -t origin/android-goldfish-3.4 -b goldfish3.4
make ARCH=arm goldfish_defconfig
make ARCH=arm SUBARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/Volumes/androidSpace/android_work/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin/arm-eabi-
```

Then I run the emulator via

```
./emulator -debug init -kernel /Volumes/androidSpace/goldfish/goldfish/arch/arm/boot/zImage -system /Volumes/androidSpace/android_work/out/target/product/generic/system.img -ramdisk /Volumes/androidSpace/android_work/out/target/product/generic/ramdisk.img -avd firstAvd -wipe-data
```

Here is the last part of the debug output from running the emulator

```
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "./emulator64-arm"
emulator: argv[01] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[02] = "/Users/deathwillarrive/.android/avd/firstAvd.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
./emulator64-arm -android-hw /Users/deathwillarrive/.android/avd/firstAvd.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x22600000,initfile=/Volumes/androidSpace/android_work/out/target/product/generic/system.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to /tmp/android-deathwillarrive/emulator-2Wyv0t
emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0xc800000,file=/Users/deathwillarrive/.android/avd/firstAvd.avd/userdata-qemu.img,initfile=/Users/deathwillarrive/.android/avd/firstAvd.avd/userdata.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '64m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '320'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'none'
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/Users/deathwillarrive/.android/avd/firstAvd.avd/cache.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 android.checkjni=1 ndns=1
emulator: Trace file name is not set

emulator: autoconfig: -scale 0.583594
emulator: Could not open file: (null)/system/build.prop: No such file or directory
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:5555' to ADB server
emulator: ping program: /Volumes/androidSpace/android_work/out/host/darwin-x86/bin/./DDSs
```

The output just freezes here. Does anybody know the steps to build 3.4 goldfish kernel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The target "goldfish_defconfig" configures the kernel for an ARM 926 but the now the emulator is configured to run on cortex A8 which is a armv7 architecture. You should use "goldfish_armv7_defconfig" instead.

Follow these steps to build a 3.4 kernel for emulator

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish.git
git checkout -t origin/android-goldfish-3.4 -b goldfish3.4

make ARCH=arm goldfish_armv7_defconfig
make ARCH=arm SUBARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/Volumes/androidSpace/android_work/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin/arm-eabi-
```

This should build a 3.4 kernel which you can then run like this (I am assuming your directory structure has default sdk ramdisk.img)

```
./emulator -debug init -kernel /Volumes/androidSpace/goldfish/goldfish/arch/arm/boot/zImage -system /Volumes/androidSpace/android_work/out/target/product/generic/system.img -ramdisk /Volumes/androidSpace/android_work/out/target/product/generic/ramdisk.img -avd firstAvd -wipe-data
```

Try this out and let us know