# How to test android Goldfish Kernel 3.10 on Versatilepb Suported QEMU?

Tags: android

```
  I'm trying to port Android on VersatilePB using [Android Goldfish 3.10 kernel](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish/+/android-goldfish-3.10).
```

First, I configured kernel for `versatile_defconfig` and I successfully built it. I got `.config` file, renamed it as `versatile_config` and added Android base configuration to that using the following command

ARCH=arm scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh versatile_config android/configs/android-base.cfg

Again, I built the kernel successfully. After that, I built the Android Google source code and I have taken `ramdisk.img` from `google_src_v4.4/out/target/product/generic`. After that, I tested using following command,

qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -kernel ./arch/arm/boot/zImage -initrd ramdisk.img -append "console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/ram0 rw" -serial stdio

but I'm getting the following error. Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000004

```
CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 3.10.0 #15
[<c001271c>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xe8) from [<c001129c>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[<c001129c>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14) from [<c0368304>] (panic+0x8c/0x1d4)
[<c0368304>] (panic+0x8c/0x1d4) from [<c001fe94>] (do_exit+0x7f8/0x8d8)
[<c001fe94>] (do_exit+0x7f8/0x8d8) from [<c001ffe0>] (do_group_exit+0x40/0xd4)
[<c001ffe0>] (do_group_exit+0x40/0xd4) from [<c002a75c>]   (get_signal_to_deliver+0x178/0x5c4)
[<c002a75c>] (get_signal_to_deliver+0x178/0x5c4) from [<c00109a4>] (do_signal+0xd0/0x434)
[<c00109a4>] (do_signal+0xd0/0x434) from [<c0010ea4>] (do_work_pending+0xa8/0xb8)
```

[] (do_work_pending+0xa8/0xb8) from [] (work_pending+0xc/0x20)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow related to the "init()" function, where kernel is trying to create the very first process (in userspace) for the first time - this is also where LInux and Android differs.    So did you use the QEMU from Android?:

https://github.com/android/platform_external_qemu

And see the discussion here:

https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/compiling-linux-kernel-for-qemu-arm-emulator/

there are some hints here:

[Run Android app in qemu-arm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627978/run-android-app-in-qemu-arm)

And here has commandline for emulation:

[How to compile android goldfish 3.4 kernel and run on emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274910/how-to-compile-android-goldfish-3-4-kernel-and-run-on-emulator)